# Performance of creating k/v pairs in dict in python

Tags: python

I have python "internal" question. I am experimenting with using a simple dict as cache (just experimenting, I know there are LRU/TTL caches). So, this cache is part of a rest server which is being hit for requests in parallel.

The server is twisted based, so everything is meant to be "non-blocking" in nature.

However, I am observing that as the cache starts getting filled in, the server "blocks" for few ms. After a while, though, things works just fine.
This happens only when I am using the cache as without cache, things are fine.

My question is.. 
say, I have a cache_dict =  {}

and then say... 1000 k/v pairs are being inserted simultaneously (in parallel), how do python internal handles these? Is there anything, which can be memory intensive in this k/v pairs inserts in the dictionary.

As, my sense is after a while, going by 80-20 rule, most of the things that are requested often are already cached, so not a lot of inserts happens during the later stages, hence I am not seeing the blocking behavior later. but initially, there are a lot of dictionary updates happening which can be bit memory intensive.

Let me know if this doesnt make sense or if this is not the right platform to ask this?

Comment: Python insertions for dicts are `O(1)` average, `O(n)` worst case (I believe, [see](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L747)). Also, hashmaps (which are what Python dictionaries are) tend to have a lot of overhead for the actual data. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "memory-intensive", Python is storing reference-counted pointers to values provided, and is not copying in the data already provided. However, it must provide book-keeping for this data, which does come with some memory overhead.

Comment: Also, Python won't insert 1000 k/v pairs in parallel, it's sequentially adding them (faster than you could implement it in pure Python) under the [hood](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L2450).

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh how does python handles dictionary resizes? Like, seems like the minium size of python dict is 8: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L111
Was wondering, if a lot of resizes are happening ?

Comment: it depends. If the object is a dict actually for what you're inserting, it can do it quite effectively by guessing the number of buckets required with minimal key overlap. Otherwise, if it's just a mapping-like object, it's a lot less performant. See `dict_merge` documentation for it (in the above link). The line below is the efficient, single-step resize: 
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L2484

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh got it.. thanks. Is there a way to like ask python to give the "Expected size" of the dict? So, if I know that I am going to eventually insert 50k objects, then maybe I can use this information?

Comment: There is no way to reserve the number of buckets like in C++ with [unordered_map::reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve), unfortunately. However, I believe using a dictionary or a sequence for the update (`PyDict_MergeFromSeq2`, `PyDict_Merge` will provide the best performance).

Comment: got it.. thanks :)